# Re-formatting string

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring

i need help., I have this date in a UIlabel in this format 04/26/2013 . How can I re format it into 04.26.2013 ?  I already have below codes:

```
UILabel *timelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xx, xx, xx, xx)];
[timelabel setText:dateToday];
```

`dateToday` value is `04/26/2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timelabel.text = [dateToday stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"."];
```

Comment: Smart! What if `dateToday` contains invalid values?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"today : %@", stringFromDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateToday];
if(date != nil) {
    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [timelabel setText:formattedDateString];
} else {
    [timelabel setText:@"Invalid Date"];
}
```

Added error checking. Always check if the input string is a valid date string or not.

Reference: [Date Formatting Guide (though it is for Mac; iOS applies the same)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)